# How do I load resources and classes at runtime in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

I am developing an Android application where additional content is downloaded at user request. This includes **images**, **sounds** and **classes**. What I need is to **load** those resources and classes **at runtime** and **use** them. Is there a way I can do this?

Edit: I need to do this for Android 2.2 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at AsyncTask and Loaders API. This will provide you the facilities to download images, resources... in a background thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, but my problem is not the download, but loading the data at runtime from the place they are downloaded. And I must make this for Android 2.2 or higher.

Comment: You can store them in the sd card, or internal memory, and then decode them. To display them, just make a Runnable to run on the UIThread.

Comment: Ok, and what about th classes? Things look more complicated here. Must I jar them? I can't imagine how I'd use them after loading at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `AsyncTask` and cache them to the local memory, SD card or hard drive. You could start the `AsyncTask` on the load, cache the data to memory, then call it when it is needed. Here are a couple links that could help you with this:

`AsyncTask`:

http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1823692&seqNum=3

Caching:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Hope this helps!